# Base64 decode gives garbled result

Tags: base64, decode, encode

I copy and paste a text from the web that is base64 encoded to this site http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp , 
but it gives a strange result , it look like a garbled.
May i ask ....how can i decode the text correctly , thank you.

```
nUł"˘ÂUÓ"…F˙i+Şž›‘Ş˘éăŁqëKĄ®qâ %˘ dŞn‘ĄŐňŢ^{łcąWq\)ńÂÔ€
```

Here is the base64 encoded text

`blWzIh+iwgYbVdODDyKFRv9pFCuqnpuRqqLp46Nx60ulrnHioCWiIARk-qm6RpdUB8t5ee7NjG7lXcVwp8cLUg==`

Comment: What makes you think it was actual “text” to begin with? Looks more like some sort of binary data.

Comment: Actually the "text" is part of the url (its fixed link)
[link](http://limst-video4.r18.com/vodstreaming/r18/amlst:vod-1:blWzIh%2BiwgYbVdODDyKFRv9pFCuqnpuRqqLp46Nx60ulrnHioCWiIARk-qm6RpdUB8t5ee7NjG7lXcVwp8cLUg%3D%3D/chunklist_b3000000.m3u8)

i'm thinking that the web site is trying to protect the actual path of the link , so they use base 64 to encode it.